# How to include For loop in Django-Viewflow Process

Tags: python, django, validation, workflow, django-viewflow

To create a process validation, I'm implementing a workflow using the "Django-Viewflow" library(http://viewflow.io/).

All works fine when i assign each task to a specific validator(user) with a fixed number of validation levels.

My problem is:

how to use this library when the number of validator change dinamically(n validation levels)?

1- choose the validators (1,2,3 or n validators).

2- use a for loop  in "flows.py" to execute the n validation tasks.

How can i include the for loop in the file "flows.py"?

**My flows.py:** (with one validation level)

```
from viewflow import flow, lock
from viewflow.base import this, Flow
from viewflow.contrib import celery

from viewflow.views import  ProcessView, StartProcessView
from viewflow.lock import select_for_update_lock
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from . import models, tasks, views

class CongeFlow(Flow):  
    process_cls = models.CongeProcess
    lock_impl = select_for_update_lock       

    start = flow.Start(views.startProcess) \
        .Next(this.assign) \

    assign = flow.View(views.approve_conge) \
        .Assign(lambda p: get_user_model().objects.get(id=p.validator1)) \
        .Next(this.check_refuse)

    check_refuse = flow.If(cond=lambda p: p.refuser) \
        .OnTrue(this.end) \
        .OnFalse(this.check_approve)   

    check_approve = flow.If(cond=lambda p: p.valider) \
        .OnTrue(this.end) \
        .OnFalse(this.assign)

    end = flow.End()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you need sequential validation by one validators, then another, you can point `flow.If` back to validation step if number of validations is not enougth.

If you would like to have validators works in parallel, you can see dynamic split example

https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/tree/master/examples/customnode